# What is the vim groupname of the '<? ?>' tag in an xml file?

Tags: xml, vim, color-scheme

I am doing my own colorscheme and I would like to customize the  tag from XML files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

But I can't find the name of the groupname.

Any one knows it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to xml.vim, the xml syntax elements and Vim groups are:

```
 +-------> xmlProcessingDelim: Comment
 | 
 |    +----------> xmlProcessing: Type
 |    |
 |    |         +--> xmlString: String
 |    |         |
 v    v         v
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

Something in your colorscheme like:

```
hi Comment guifg=#999999
```

Might achieve the desired result of coloring `<? ?>`

Answer (score 1):

I've had a look in syntax/xml.vim, and there's a region called xmlProcessing that might be what you're looking for? This is then mapped to the 'Type' group.

Answer (score 1):

To get all names of all groups that affect highlighting of a symbol under cursor, use

```
echo 'Normal '.join(map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")'))
```

It will echo something like this:

```
Normal helpHyperTextEntry helpStar
```

(it is for star in tags in help files).

You may want to use

```
echo 'Normal '.join(map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(synIDtrans(v:val), "name")'))
```

as well. More info at `:h synstack()` and `:h synIDtrans()`.

After you found a name of desired group you can put something like

```
hi xmlProcessingDelim ctermbg=Yellow
```

into ~/.vim/after/syntax/xml.vim.