# What is vim syntax name for printf placement %d within strings?

Tags: vim, colors, syntax-highlighting

Within `printf` format strings, the placement characters, from `%` to the corresponding `d`, or `x` appear in dark blue. With a black background, they are very hard to read.

To change the color, I know I have to change the color with a command like this:

```
highlight Comment ctermfg=Cyan
```

But I have to put the correct syntax group name instead of `Comment`.

Does anyone know what this syntax group name is?

Comment: Have you `:set background=dark`? This might change the colors to be readable without any explicit `highlight` commands.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003057/what-is-the-vim-groupname-of-the-tag-in-an-xml-file/6003162#6003162

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `cFormat`. You can check what group is under the cursor by executing:

```
:echo synIDattr(synID(line("."),col("."),1),"name")
```

Answer (score 2):

That group's name is `cFormat`.